# delete NAs to move data up, no stairs anymore

Tags: r, move, na

The data file that I get from an experiment looks like this

```
VP Selbst ES          eigForm eigES      andForm andES      MM   MMRT  Wunschform Geschlecht Muttersprache Alter
99 1      unhöflich   NA                 NA                            NA         NA         NA            NA
99 5      gesellig    NA                 NA                            NA         NA         NA            NA
99 6      ehrlich     NA                 NA                            NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA                 5       gründlich  NA                            NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA                 6       treu       NA                            NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA                 5       romantisch NA                            NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA                 NA                 6        stark                NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA                 NA                 3        klein                NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA                 NA                 5        rational             NA         NA         NA            NA   
99 NA     ordentlich  NA                 NA                ["y"] [0.4] NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA     sentimental NA                 NA                ["n"] [0.5] NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA     warm        NA                 NA                ["n"] [0.4] NA         NA         NA            NA 
99 NA                 NA                 NA                            1          2          1             24
```

So kind of like stairs. The only column that is filled from bottom to top is the first one with the participant id. The others are arranged in order how they appeared in the experiment. The colors are in a random order in the experiment. ratingS and color belong together as well as ratingOw are the ratings for the colors presented in the routine Ow and same for ratingOt and colorOt

What I want is to get rid of these NAs (empty fields) and get something like this instead:

```
VP Selbst ES          eigForm eigES      andForm andES      MM   MMRT  Wunschform Geschlecht Muttersprache Alter
99 1      unhöflich   5       gründlich  6       stark                 NA         NA         NA            NA
99 5      gesellig    6       treu       3       klein                 NA         NA         NA            NA
99 6      ehrlich     5       romantisch 5       rational              NA         NA         NA            NA

99 NA     ordentlich  NA                 NA                ["y"] [0.4] NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA     sentimental NA                 NA                ["n"] [0.5] NA         NA         NA            NA
99 NA     warm        NA                 NA                ["n"] [0.4] NA         NA         NA            NA 
99 NA                 NA                 NA                            1          2          1             24
```

or even:

```
VP Selbst ES          eigForm eigES      andForm andES    ES          MM   MMRT  Wunschform Geschlecht Muttersprache Alter
99 1      unhöflich   5       gründlich  6       stark    ordentlich ["y"] [0.4] 1          2          1             24 
99 5      gesellig    6       treu       3       klein    sentimental["n"] [0.5] 1          2          1             24    
99 6      ehrlich     5       romantisch 5       rational warm       ["n"] [0.4] 1          2          1             24
```

Note: the empty fields are empty in my data as well (no "NA").
Can this be done with reshape? Any solution is appreciated
Maybe, @Onyambu can you help?

```
dput(datnew)
structure(list(VP = c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L), Selbst = c(1L, 5L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ES = structure(c(85L, 31L, 19L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 60L, 72L, 90L, 1L), .Label = c("", "abhängig", 
"aggressiv", "aktiv", "albern", "ängstlich", "arrogant", "attraktiv", 
"belastbar", "besorgt", "clever", "dankbar", "dick", "direkt", 
"dominant", "dünn", "egoistisch", "ehrgeizig", "ehrlich", "eigensinnig", 
"eitel", "emotional", "empfindlich", "faul", "flexibel", "freundlich", 
"furchtlos", "geduldig", "genau", "gerecht", "gesellig", "gierig", 
"glücklich", "grob", "groß", "gründlich", "hektisch", "herzlich", 
"hilflos", "hilfsbereit", "intelligent", "kalt", "klein", "kleinlich", 
"konsequent", "kreativ", "kritisch", "langweilig", "laut", "lieb", 
"loyal", "lustig", "modern ", "nachlässig", "nervös", "nett", 
"neugierig", "objektiv", "offen", "ordentlich", "passiv", "primitiv", 
"rational", "reizbar", "roh", "romantisch", "sachlich", "schwach", 
"selbstbewusst", "selbstlos", "sensibel", "sentimental", "sicher", 
"sinnlich", "sozial", "sparsam", "sportlich", "stark", "stur", 
"tolerant", "träge", "treu", "umsichtig", "undiszipliniert", 
"unhöflich", "unnahbar", "verletzlich", "vielseitig", "vorsichtig", 
"warm", "weinerlich", "zielstrebig"), class = "factor"), eigForm = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 5L, 6L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), eigES = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 36L, 82L, 66L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"abhängig", "aggressiv", "aktiv", "albern", "ängstlich", "arrogant", 
"attraktiv", "belastbar", "besorgt", "clever", "dankbar", "dick", 
"direkt", "dominant", "dünn", "egoistisch", "ehrgeizig", "ehrlich", 
"eigensinnig", "eitel", "emotional", "empfindlich", "faul", "flexibel", 
"freundlich", "furchtlos", "geduldig", "genau", "gerecht", "gesellig", 
"gierig", "glücklich", "grob", "groß", "gründlich", "hektisch", 
"herzlich", "hilflos", "hilfsbereit", "intelligent", "kalt", 
"klein", "kleinlich", "konsequent", "kreativ", "kritisch", "langweilig", 
"laut", "lieb", "loyal", "lustig", "modern ", "nachlässig", 
"nervös", "nett", "neugierig", "objektiv", "offen", "ordentlich", 
"passiv", "primitiv", "rational", "reizbar", "roh", "romantisch", 
"sachlich", "schwach", "selbstbewusst", "selbstlos", "sensibel", 
"sentimental", "sicher", "sinnlich", "sozial", "sparsam", "sportlich", 
"stark", "stur", "tolerant", "träge", "treu", "umsichtig", "undiszipliniert", 
"unhöflich", "unnahbar", "verletzlich", "vielseitig", "vorsichtig", 
"warm", "weinerlich", "zielstrebig"), class = "factor"), andForm = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA), andES = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 78L, 43L, 63L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"abhängig", "aggressiv", "aktiv", "albern", "ängstlich", "arrogant", 
"attraktiv", "belastbar", "besorgt", "clever", "dankbar", "dick", 
"direkt", "dominant", "dünn", "egoistisch", "ehrgeizig", "ehrlich", 
"eigensinnig", "eitel", "emotional", "empfindlich", "faul", "flexibel", 
"freundlich", "furchtlos", "geduldig", "genau", "gerecht", "gesellig", 
"gierig", "glücklich", "grob", "groß", "gründlich", "hektisch", 
"herzlich", "hilflos", "hilfsbereit", "intelligent", "kalt", 
"klein", "kleinlich", "konsequent", "kreativ", "kritisch", "langweilig", 
"laut", "lieb", "loyal", "lustig", "modern ", "nachlässig", 
"nervös", "nett", "neugierig", "objektiv", "offen", "ordentlich", 
"passiv", "primitiv", "rational", "reizbar", "roh", "romantisch", 
"sachlich", "schwach", "selbstbewusst", "selbstlos", "sensibel", 
"sentimental", "sicher", "sinnlich", "sozial", "sparsam", "sportlich", 
"stark", "stur", "tolerant", "träge", "treu", "umsichtig", "undiszipliniert", 
"unhöflich", "unnahbar", "verletzlich", "vielseitig", "vorsichtig", 
"warm", "weinerlich", "zielstrebig"), class = "factor"), MM = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"[\"n\"]", "[\"z\"]"), class = "factor"), MMRT = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"[0.42799997329711914]", "[0.4609997272491455]", "[0.46399974822998047]", 
"[0.46699976921081543]", "[0.49199986457824707]", "[0.49899983406066895]", 
"[0.4999997615814209]", "[0.5069997310638428]", "[0.5079998970031738]", 
"[0.5160000324249268]", "[0.5179998874664307]", "[0.5189998149871826]", 
"[0.5239999294281006]", "[0.5249998569488525]", "[0.5269997119903564]", 
"[0.5319998264312744]", "[0.5339996814727783]", "[0.5349998474121094]", 
"[0.5360000133514404]", "[0.5459997653961182]", "[0.557999849319458]", 
"[0.5649998188018799]", "[0.5659997463226318]", "[0.5669999122619629]", 
"[0.5689997673034668]", "[0.5729999542236328]", "[0.5739998817443848]", 
"[0.5749998092651367]", "[0.5779998302459717]", "[0.5829999446868896]", 
"[0.5839998722076416]", "[0.5919997692108154]", "[0.5969998836517334]", 
"[0.6079998016357422]", "[0.6099996566772461]", "[0.6099998950958252]", 
"[0.6109998226165771]", "[0.6159999370574951]", "[0.618999719619751]", 
"[0.622999906539917]", "[0.6269998550415039]", "[0.6309998035430908]", 
"[0.6399998664855957]", "[0.6419999599456787]", "[0.6509997844696045]", 
"[0.6529998779296875]", "[0.6549997329711914]", "[0.6569998264312744]", 
"[0.6579999923706055]", "[0.6589999198913574]", "[0.6669998168945312]", 
"[0.6749997138977051]", "[0.6809999942779541]", "[0.6840000152587891]", 
"[0.6899998188018799]", "[0.6940000057220459]", "[0.6999998092651367]", 
"[0.7019996643066406]", "[0.7079999446868896]", "[0.7159998416900635]", 
"[0.7179999351501465]", "[0.7209997177124023]", "[0.7239999771118164]", 
"[0.7339999675750732]", "[0.7639997005462646]", "[0.7679998874664307]", 
"[0.7739999294281006]", "[0.7769997119903564]", "[0.7779998779296875]", 
"[0.7819998264312744]", "[0.7909998893737793]", "[0.7949998378753662]", 
"[0.7979998588562012]", "[0.7999999523162842]", "[0.8169999122619629]", 
"[0.8220000267028809]", "[0.8339998722076416]", "[0.8619997501373291]", 
"[0.931999683380127]", "[1.001999855041504]", "[1.0429999828338623]", 
"[1.1759998798370361]", "[1.2819998264312744]"), class = "factor"), 
    Wunschform = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1L), Geschlecht = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2L), Muttersprache = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Alter = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24L)), row.names = c(21L, 22L, 
23L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 395L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I don't think that this is what you wanted. I typed it in R and copied. Is that right?

Comment: in order for us to have the same mock data that you have, consider running `dput(your_example)` and copy that then paste it here.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: The output of `dput` does not match the example data frame you provide at the top of the question.

Comment: The dput data you posted is not the one you gave above. How did you post the very first data here? Now do `dput(your_example_data)` then post that

Comment: @HonestRlover.not. Still no one is able to replicate your issue because we are unable to get the data. The data you gave above from `dput` is not the one provided at the top of the question. to make this simple, edit you data at the top of the question by including data delimiter such as `,` or `|` e.g `23|1|blue|NA|NA|...etc`. Do that for all the rows

Comment: Hey I'm sorry I only saw it now. So now I changed the above. Is it also ok like this? The only difference between the example above and the real data is now that there aren't only 3 lines each time but 91 but I thought it would not be helpful to write them all down.

Comment: could you try `(do.call(data.frame,lapply(\`is.na<-\`(df,df==""),function(x)x[order(is.na(x))]))->a)[rowSums(!is.na(a))>1,]`

Comment: Could you explain that code to me? Cause I think it works fine for me but if I add another dataframe from a second participant with rbind at the beginning, it does not differentiate between these two anymore. So I have got twice as many rows (which is correct) but they are all VP 99 (VP is like the id). This is propably because VP is the only column which doesn't have any NAs

Answer (score 1):

`df[] = lapply(df, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])` will put all the `NA`s at the bottom, while preserving the order of everything else.

We can then either use `na.omit()` on the ordered data to get your short result, or omit the rows where everything is `NA` for the long result.

```
# replace "" with NA
datnew[] = lapply(datnew, function(x) {x[x == ""] <- NA; return(x)})

# order each column
datnew[] <- lapply(datnew, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])

# short result - remove rows with any NA values
na.omit(datnew)

# long result - remove rows that are all NA, skipping the first column
datnew[!apply(is.na(datnew[-1]), 1, all), ]
```

Comment: Order worked but if I omit the NAs with the long result (the short doesn't do anything) there is only one line left and still the columns which are not integers are empty

Comment: A good first step would be to replace all empty values `""` with `NA`.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: The best way would be to do it when you import that data - the command you use to read the data in probably has an argument like `na.strings` that you could use so that the `""` are marked as `NA` from the start. If that's not an option, `df[] = lapply(df, function(x) {x[x == ""] <- NA; return(x)})` should do it. (Added to answer.)

Comment: I also added an edit for the long result so that the first column isn't considered, since it seems to always be non-missing.